# Elastic Search : How to query range for String fields (of numbers)

Tags: elasticsearch, range, kibana

> ive string field which contains numbers.
>
> eg : minRange: "2500"

**my query is**:

```
"range": {
                      "minRange": {
                        "from": 2000,
                        "to": null,
                        "include_lower": true,
                        "include_upper": true
                      }
                    }
```

This query is not working..How could i resolve this?

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33790075/range-strange-results/33795464#33795464

Answer (score 0):

The RangeQuery provided by the elasticsearch internally uses the Lucene TermRangeQuery(which as far as I know doesn't analyze the term to search for) for the field of type string. On the other hand, it uses the Lucene NumericRangeQuery for a field of type number/date. (Note: from is "2000" instead of 2000 like in your questions)

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "minRange": {
        "from": "2000",
        "to": null,
        "include_lower": true,
        "include_upper": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```